# Expected number of primes of particular size and from a linear form

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Given two distinct primes $P_1$ and $P_2$ picked randomly and uniformly in the interval $[T^2,2T^2]$ consider the set $\chi(P_1,P_2)$ of numbers of form $$xP_1-yP_2$$ where $x,y$ are in $[0,T^{1+\epsilon}]$ where $T>0$ and $\epsilon\geq0$ is small.

> Are there expected to be at least $\frac{T^\mu}{O(\log T)}$ many distinct primes in the set $\chi(P_1,P_2)$ which are of size $T^{1+\mu}$ for small $\mu\geq0$?
>
> If not what is the correct asymptotic at least under appropriate assumptions?

Assume $T^{\min(\mu, \epsilon)}=\omega(\mathsf{polylog}(T))$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $\chi(P_1,P_2)$ has $T^{2+2\epsilon}$ distinct elements in $[-2T^{3+\epsilon},T^{3+\epsilon}]$  (i.e., density of order $T^{\epsilon-1}$),
so we would expect $\chi(P_1,P_2)$ to contain about $T^{\mu+\epsilon}$ elements in $[C_1T^{1+\mu}, C_2T^{1+\mu}]$ provided that $0<C_1<C_2$.   Of these, a fraction of about $1/(\log T)$ should be primes, leading to a prediction of about
$$\frac{T^{\mu+\epsilon}}{\log T}$$ primes in $[C_1T^{1+\mu}, C_2T^{1+\mu}]$ .

Comment: "should be primes".. is the relevant theorem prime number theorem?

Comment: @Turbo Yes, but note that this is just a prediction, not a proof. If you consider a random model for the primes, where each integer $k$ is quasiprime with probability $1/(\log k)$, then you arrive at this prediction.

Comment: A small variation. What if $x,y$ are also primes? Then it should be expected there are $\frac{T^{\mu+\epsilon}}{(\log T)^3}$ primes in $[C_1T^{1+\mu},C_2T^{1+\mu}]$ correct?

Comment: @Turbo: Yes, that is the natural prediction.